# Fixing micro-cracks in a fiberglass tub

Tags: bathtub, fiberglass

I am experiencing leakage from my tub. It is inconsistent with a small amount of water, but it happens to leak onto the computers below. After multiple plumbers reviewed the plumbing and found no issues, we have come to the conclusion that is coming from micro-cracks in the tub. We have a temporary workaround with a bath mat and spreading our feet wider on the tub, but these are hacks.

We are trying to figure out a more permanent solution. The obvious answer is to replace the entire thing, but that is very involved and costly. Is there some kind of sealant that we could use or another similar strategy that would address the issue and avoid total replacement? While I have some home improvement knowledge, my experience is non-existing when it comes to installing and managing tubs and so am not sure if that will influence any recommendations.

TIA!

[image]

Comment: "it happens to leak onto the computers below" What? Computers stored under... your bath tub? Going to need more context about the bathtub's environment here...

Comment: No, my office happens is on the floor below my bathtub. The water leaks from the tub onto the computers on my desk on the floor below. It is a small flow and they are covered with a towel. Not ideal for sure. However, the temporary fix has stopped the problem. But as posted in the original question, it is really a hack, and I need a permanent solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tub coatings are not intended to be structural. They're merely aesthetic (and maybe hygienic). A *fix* would involve bolstering the tub enough to stop flex movement (from underneath), plus a resurfacing, and even that may be unreliable.

That all would cost as much in time and expense as a new tub. Unless you're willing to bathe in the equivalent of a pickup bed coated with spray-on liner, you need a new tub.